# Combination of INSERT and SELECT statement causes error in VB

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, recordset

Here's my SQL Server stored procedure

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[insRequestVote]  
     @fkRequest     int,  
     @fkOrganisation    int,  
     @fkUser            int  
AS 
   IF NOT Exists(SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[tblRequestVote] 
                 WHERE [fkRequest] = @fkRequest 
                   AND [fkOrganisation] = @fkOrganisation 
                   AND [fkUser] = @fkUser)
   BEGIN
       /* This user from this organisation has not yet voted for this request */ 
       INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblRequestVote] ([fkRequest], [fkOrganisation],[fkUser], [DateStamp])
       VALUES (@fkRequest, @fkOrganisation, @fkUser, GetDate());

       SELECT 
           'Inserted' AS VoteResult;
   END
   ELSE
      SELECT 'You have already voted for this SR' AS VoteResult;
```

When I run this in T-SQL, it works perfectly, e.g.

```
insRequestVote 1, 4, 23
```

will return the required phrase. However, when I call the stored procedure from VB.NET, it only writes the record to the table, but doesn't return the phrase.

Code behind:

```
Dim ADOConn As New ADODB.Connection  
ADOConn.ConnectionString = WFConnectionString  
If (ADOConn.State <> ConnectionState.Open) Then ADOConn.Open()  
Dim ADORecSet As New ADODB.Recordset  
Dim sSql As String = ""  

Try  
    '----// Save the Vote for the SR  
    sSql = "dbo.insRequestVote " & row.Cells(0).Text & "," & row.Cells(1).Text & "," & row.Cells(2).Text
    ADORecSet = ADOConn.Execute(sSql)  

   If Not ADORecSet.EOF Then  
      If ADORecSet.Fields("VoteResult").Value = "Inserted" Then  
         gridSRs.DataBind()  
         row.Cells(4).Text = "1"  
      End If  
   End If  

   ADORecSet.Close()  
Catch GenEx As Exception  
   '----- Catch-all  
   LogAction(Session("WhoAmI"), GenEx.Message, "Error")  
Finally  
   ADOConn.Close()  
   ADOConn = Nothing  
End Try
```

This all works fine up to the "If Not ADORecSet.EOF Then" statement, where it jumps to the exception line. The exception message is

> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

My question is: why does the specific pattern work in all cases except where I have the combination of an INSERT and a SELECT in one stored procedure?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it! Just in case someone else is trying this, here is my modified code:

```
Dim SQLConn As New SqlConnection(WFConnectionStringNET)
If (SQLConn.State <> ConnectionState.Open) Then SQLConn.Open()

Dim sSql As String = ""
Try
                '----// Save the Vote for the SR
                sSql = "dbo.insRequestVote " & Mid(row.Cells(0).Text, 2, InStr(row.Cells(0).Text, ":") - 2) & "," &
                                               Session("ThisUserOrganisationID") & "," &
                                               Session("ThisUserID")
                Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(sSql, SQLConn)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@fkRequest", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Mid(row.Cells(0).Text, 2, InStr(row.Cells(0).Text, ":") - 2)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@fkOrganisation", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("ThisUserOrganisationID")
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@fkUser", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("ThisUserID")
                Dim sqlDR As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

                While sqlDR.Read()
                    If sqlDR("VoteResult") = "Inserted" Then
                        gridSRs.DataBind()
                        row.Cells(4).Text = "1"
                    End If
                End While
                sqlDR.Close()

                LogAction(Session("WhoAmI"), "Voted for SR " & row.Cells(5).Text)

            Catch GenEx As Exception
                '-----// Catch-all
                LogAction(Session("WhoAmI"), GenEx.Message, "Error")
            Finally
                SQLConn.Close()
                SQLConn = Nothing
            End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

Where do we start... Your code is riddled with anti patterns. You should read up on proper use of ado, our switch to something simpler like an ORM. That aside:

1. *NEVER* dynamically build a string to execute in SQL from user inputs. Always, always, always use parameterized queries. Otherwise I can drop all of your db tables from your text box and it is trivial to do.
2. Since this is a stored procedure you you should set the command type to that and not use text. This can otherwise cause oddities with return value, and it's bad practice.
3. You tag this as vb. Net but you are using legacy ADO? Use ADO. Net which returns datasets, not long deprecated recordsets

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I was under the impression that the code that I am using is ADO.NET. Could you please tell me what my code should look like using ADO.NET?